# Perl: Pushing a tab-delimited file into an array and going through every element after a specific column number

Tags: perl

I am fairly new to perl and I have this text file that I'm trying to format.

Here is an example of what the tab-delimitedfile looks like:

```
Num Let Re  Al  Samp1   Samp2   Samp3   Samp4   Samp5

1    dog    R    R    ./.    0/0    ./.    0/0    0/0

2    dog    S    P    0/0    ./.    0/1     ./.     ./.

3    cat    P   P    0/1    ./.     ./.     0/0     0/1

4    horse    S     S    0/0    0/0    0/0    ./.    0/1

5   cow     P    R  ./.     0/1     ./.     ./.    ./.
```

I want the program to go through this entire file. So if you are going row by row, it when it gets to 0/0, it needs to replace that with "Re" value of that row. If there is a 0/1, it needs to replace that with the "Al" value of that row. And for everything else, just replace it with 'NA'. I also was to just join the first two columns (Num:Let). Here is the example output:

```
Num:Let Re  Al  Samp1   Samp2   Samp3   Samp4   Samp5

1:dog    R    R    NA    R    NA    R    R

2:dog    S    P    S    NA  P   NA  NA

3:cat    P  P    P  NA  NA  P   P

4:horse    S     S    S    S    S    NA    S

5:cow   P    R  NA  R   NA  NA    NA
```

Also, this is just an example. The actual file probably has more than 5 of the "Samp" columns. I tried splitting the file into an array and going through every element of the array using foreach loop. Then I used if-else statements to check for these conditions and replace that element if the condition is met but for some reason, it just makes all the "Samp" elements the same letter that I replaced it with. In short, I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: And we don't know what you're doing wrong, either, because you haven't posted any code. ;-) You should [edit] your question to include the code that isn't working. (Also fix the formatting of your sample data while you're in there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it...

```
my $header = <DATA>;
print join("\t", split(' ', $header)), "\n";

while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
    my ($num, $let, $re, $al, @samps) = split(' ', $row);
    my @reals = map {
        if    ( m{0/0} ) { $re  }
        elsif ( m{0/1} ) { $al  }
        else             { 'NA' }
    } @samps;
    print join("\t", $num, $let, $re, $al, @reals), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Num Let Re  Al  Samp1   Samp2   Samp3   Samp4   Samp5
1    dog    R    R    ./.    0/0    ./.    0/0    0/0
2    dog    S    P    0/0    ./.    0/1     ./.     ./.
3    cat    P   P    0/1    ./.     ./.     0/0     0/1
4    horse    S     S    0/0    0/0    0/0    ./.    0/1
5   cow     P    R  ./.     0/1     ./.     ./.    ./.
```

OUTPUT

```
Num     Let     Re      Al      Samp1   Samp2   Samp3   Samp4   Samp5
1       dog     R       R       NA      R       NA      R       R
2       dog     S       P       S       NA      P       NA      NA
3       cat     P       P       P       NA      NA      P       P
4       horse   S       S       S       S       S       NA      S
5       cow     P       R       NA      R       NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and it also tells me why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
my @col;

my %data;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    next unless /^\d+/;
    s/\.\/\./NA/g; # swap all ./. for NA
    @col = split;
    s/0\/0/$col[2]/ foreach @col; # swap all 0/0 for 2nd field
    s/0\/1/$col[3]/ foreach @col; # swap all 0/1 for 3rd field
    $data{$col[0]} = [ @col[1..8]];
}

print join ("\t", qw(NumLet Re Al Samp1 Samp2 Samp3 Samp4 Samp5));
print "\n";

for (sort keys %data){
    print join("\t", $_, @{$data{$_}});
    print "\n";
}
```

---

```
NumLet  Re  Al  Samp1   Samp2   Samp3   Samp4   Samp5
1   dog R   R   NA  R   NA  R   R
2   dog S   P   S   NA  P   NA  NA
3   cat P   P   P   NA  NA  P   P
4   horse   S   S   S   S   S   NA  S
5   cow P   R   NA  R   NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Consider using curlies `{}` (or `|`) when you are dealing strings with forward slashes, ie `s{0/0}{$col[2]}g` or `s|0/0|$col[2]|g`